# if filename == "file" returns nothing when the file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

Something so simple is not working for me. I want to `os.walk` through my subdirectories and if there is a specific filename that equals to `__main__.py` I want to execute a command

The file I'm using is below, and so is my other attempt. I'm sure I'm blind or forgetting something, thought reaching out to StackOverflow might catch something I can't see

This file below is the one I'm using, and the one below it provides proof the file is there in a subdirectory.

#### file.py

```
import os

def a():

    current_dir = os.getcwd()

    # Scans all files in bot directory 
    for dirs in os.walk(current_dir):
        for file in dirs:
            # Checks if filename "__main__.py" is there
            if file == '__main__.py':
                print("Found __main__.py")
            else:
                pass
```

When I do this:

```
import os

def a():

    current_dir = os.getcwd()

    # Scans all files in bot directory 
    for dirs in os.walk(current_dir):
        for file in dirs:
            print (file)
```

It returns this: (You can see that **main**.py is in the file, but the script at the very top of this post cannot see it)

```
['justinbieber', 'daviddobrik']
['.DS_Store']
/Users/path/1/justinbieber
['__pycache__', 'output_path']
['auth.py', 'run.py', 'startup.py', '.DS_Store', 'downloader.py', 'organize.py', 'constants.py', '__init__.py', 'assembler.py', 'logger.py', 'pil.py', 'helpers.py', '__main__.py', 'dlfuncs.py', 'comments.py']
/Users/path/1/justinbieber/__pycache__
```

Comment: did you read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk what do you expect `os.walk` to return?

Comment: `os.walk` returns alls file names in all subdirectories, `os.listdir` can't do that. Unless there is a better way to find all `__main__.py` in subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `os.listdir`

```
 def a():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()

    # Scans all files in bot directory
    for file in os.listdir(current_dir):
        if file == "__main__.py":
            print("Found __main__.py")

        else:
            pass

 a()
```

using os.walk

```
   def a():

      current_dir = os.getcwd()          
      # Scans all files in bot directory
      for dirs,subdirs,files in os.walk(current_dir):
         for file in files:
           # Checks if filename "__main__.py" is there
            if file == '__main__.py':
                print("Found __main__.py")
            else:
                pass

    a()
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and it didn't work because I need subdirectories, `os.walk` fixes that

Comment: Works! I guess I forgot to add `dirs, subdirs, and files` to `os.walk`